# PyQt4 : ImportError: cannot import name Signal

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am very new to Python and trying to run an Python application. I have Installed python 2.6, Qt4.8 and PyQt4.8.
when I run this command

```
 python mygui.py
```

I got this result

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.6 gtk/__init__.py:122:

RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
set_interactive(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mgui.py", line 1069, in <module>
main()
File "mgui.py", line 1053, in main
mWindow =  MWindow()
File "mgui.py", line 173, in __init__
self.setPlugin('default', '/')
File "mgui.py", line 365, in setPlugin
self.plugin = self.loadPluginClass(str(name))(str(root), self)
File "mgui.py", line 310, in loadPluginClass
pluginModule = self.loadPluginModule(name, re=re)
File "mgui.py", line 262, in loadPluginModule
module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
File "/hm1/dinesh/moose-master/moose-master/gui/plugins/default.py", 
line      822, in <module>
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot,SIGNAL,SLOT, Signal, pyqtSignal

ImportError: cannot import name Signal
```

I tried to find out the soln in google but could not understood.
I will be thankful if any one can solve my following doubt -

1) RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
set_interactive(1)

2) ImportError: cannot import name Signal

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It seems like `Signal` and `pyqtSignal` are not in `QtCore`. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtcore.html . Does it work if you remove them ?

Comment: What is this `mygui.py` script? Presumably it is not something you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [the PyQt4 documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtcore.html) you'll see that there's SIGNAL in this package, but not Signal. So, to fix this problem, go to mgui.py, find every `Signal`, and replace them with SIGNAL.